# AnyObject.Protocol error with dataWithJSONObject in Swift

Tags: ios, swift2

Since Apple decided to change error handling to a much more circuitous system, I'm having trouble updating a line of code in Xcode 7 and am getting an error I'm not familiar with.

I receive an error of: Argument type 'AnyObject.Protocol' does not conform to expected type 'AnyObject'

Here's my old code which used to work:

```
request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
```

And my current code which is throwing the above error:

```
do {
    request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(obj: AnyObject, options: nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not be completed due to \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
do {
    let request = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not be completed due to \(error)")
}
```